# Minimization of $||Ax -b||$ for a full rank matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, solution-verification, least-squares

I need a check on the following exercise, **especially on the first point**

> Let $A$ be a real $m$-by-$n$ matrix with $m>n$ **with full rank**, and define
>
> $$M = \begin{bmatrix}I & A \\ A^T & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> i) Show that the $x$ component of the solution of $$M \begin{bmatrix} -r \\ x\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ minimize $||Ax-b||_2$.
>
> ii) Find an explicit formula for $M^{-1}$ in terms of $A$ and $A^T$

---

i) Solving the block system I get the equations $$Ax-b = r$$ and $$A^T r = 0$$

Therefore $||A x- b|| = ||r||$. Now, I have to use the fact that the matrix $A$ has full rank, i.e. it is $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$, but I don't know how to move.
I would say that this implies that $r=0$ is a solution, therefore the norm is minimized, but I don't know if it's right.

ii) This one is easy: reasoning with blocks, I found $$M^{-1}= \frac{1}{\det{A^TA}}\begin{bmatrix}0 & -A \\ -A^T & I \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Part (i): suppose $Ax_0-b=r$ and $A^Tr=0$. For any vector $x$, let $v=x-x_0$. Then
\begin{aligned}
\|Ax-b\|^2
&= \|A(v+x_0)-b)\|^2\\
&= \|Av+r\|^2 \\
&= (Av+r)^T(Av+r)\\
&= v^TA^TAv + v^TA^Tr + r^TAv + r^Tr\\
&= v^TA^TAv + r^Tr\\
&= \|Av\|^2 + \|r\|^2\\
&\geq \|r\|^2 = \|Ax_0-b\|^2.\\
\end{aligned}
Therefore $x_0$ minimizes $\|Ax-b\|$.

Part (ii): your answer is wrong. $M^{-1}=\pmatrix{I-A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T&A(A^TA)^{-1}\\ (A^TA)^{-1}A^T&-(A^TA)^{-1}}$.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you compute $M^{-1}$? (using the analogy with the 2x2 inverse matrix?)

Comment: Also, where are you using the fact that $A$ is full rank?

Comment: @andereBen The rank of $A$ is irrelevant in part (i). That $A$ has full column rank guarantees that $A^TA$ is invertible in part (ii). To find $M^{-1}$, solve $MX=I$ blockwise directly.

Comment: But In i), $r=0$, since $A$ il full rank, right?

Comment: @andereBen No. Consider e.g. $A=\pmatrix{1\\ 0},\,x=0$ and $b=-r=\pmatrix{0\\ 1}$.

Comment: Ok, now I got my mistake: $A$ is full rank, and hence $A x =0$ implies $x=0$, but $A^t y =0$ does not imply $y=0$!